# How to make a part change color between 2

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm in Roblox and I wanna make a part change color randomly BUT, it only has two choices blue, or red. I only have

```
local block = script.parent
block.touched:Connect(function()
    block.brickcolor = math.random(brickcolor.red, brickcolor.blue)
end)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to define your colors, put them into an array, then use a random number to choose which index to pick :

```
-- put the colors into an array of choices
local colors = { BrickColor.Red(), BrickColor.Blue() }

local block = script.parent
block.Touched:Connect(function()
    -- pick a random index in the array
    local index = math.random(#colors)

    -- set the color
    block.BrickColor = colors[index]
end)
```

This format will work with any number of colors you add to the `colors` array. And if you want truly random numbers, feel free to add this to the top of the Script :

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
```

Comment: instead of `math.floor(math.random(1, #colors) + 0.5)`  you can simply call `math.random(#colors)`. math.random returns integer values if called with arguments. also you should probably set a suitable seed value so you don't get the same numbers every time.

Comment: Oh that is much nicer! Lemme edit my answer to include it.