# Can I make math.random set brick colors?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm playing roblox and I want to develop a script where when <kbd>Del</kbd> is pressed, it will choose a random number from 1-3. I have 3 parts, one named one, one named two, and one named three. Whichever number `math.random` chooses, it sets the corresponding brick of that number to Lime Green. This one doesn't work because it's going in a pattern of 2,3,1 and I want it random. I've tried 8 times and it's gone in the exactly same pattern every time. Anyways, here's my script:

```
local choices = { game.Workspace.one.Part, game.Workspace.two.Part, game.Workspace.three.Part }
local space = game.Workspace
local P1 = space.one
local P2 = space.two
local P3 = space.three
local uis = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer

uis.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.Delete then
        local index = math.random(#choices)
        choices[index].BrickColor = BrickColor.new(0, 255, 0)
        wait(15)
        choices[index].BrickColor = BrickColor.Black()
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Lua < 5.4 you need to set a random seed yourself. Otherwise math.random will create the same sequence of random numbers every time you execute your script.

A common way to get a new seed every time is to use the system time as a seed value.

Call `math.randomseed(os.time())` at the beginning of your script.

See https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/lua-docs/math

This was actually part of the answer to [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70838375/how-to-make-a-part-change-color-between-2). (Roblox's Lua is derived from Lua 5.1)

Please read answers carefully.